# Get documents matching type 1 and not in type 2

Tags: elasticsearch

I've an index structure where types are dates and each type has several documents. I want to get all documents present in type-1 but must be absent in type-2. As an example:

```
Type-1 ---> id list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Type-2 ---> id list = [2,3,7,8,9]
```

The query i'm looking for should return documents from type-1 only with id = [1,4,5,6]
I'm using es-py client for the above purpose.

PS: I can always get documents matching type-1 and type-2 individually followed by iterating through both of them to get what i need. But this is a solution i want to avoid for sake of performance.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was, that your question is about the difference (subtraction) of the documents sets of two types. But as you mentioned you can not have the same document in two types but the same id in two documents [(_uid = _type#_id)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html)

So your question is about a [join-Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html): 
You need the complement of all _id-Values in type-1 which also belongs to type-2.

You could use a [Parent-Child-Relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) for this, but in this case you have to change your index-Process.

Unfortunately there is no other "build in" join between two types in elasticsearch (e.g. solr would help).

You could get all ids from the join by an aggregation and build the complement without elasticsearch, but this will only work for small sets for type-1.

So from my point of view you need to build your own search plugin analog to [ParentJoinPlugin](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/plugin/parent-join-client/5.6.2/org/elasticsearch/join/ParentJoinPlugin.html)

Starting point would be:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.6.2/modules/parent-join/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/join/query/HasParentQueryBuilder.java

But be aware: If the documents of type-1 belongs to an other shard then type-2 you can not join even with your own SearchPlugin.

Comment: This is NOT going to solve the requirement. Your query will give me all documents having Type-1 but not having Type-2 (that is equivalent to giving all documents of Type-1). If the same _id is found in both types then it shouldn't be returned as part of the response(but it'll according to your query)

Comment: OK, you are right: One document can not be in two types. So I will change my answer.